# How to set image in list view by using string

Tags: list, listview, adapter, listadapter

I have two activities namely mainactivity and main2activity. Mainactivity  has three buttons and main2activity has list view.
When I click button string is passed to main2activity and is displayed in main2activity.
So now I want also  image in `listview`. corresponding image for button selected. Below are my codes.

MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editText;

    Button addButton;
    String text1 ="Item 1";
    String text2 ="Item 2";
    String text3 ="Item 3";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("text",text1);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("text",text2);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("text",text3);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
}
```

Main2activity

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Global.list1);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        if (Global.list1.size() < 1) {
            Global.list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Intent intent1 = getIntent();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Global.list1);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        String havestring = intent1.getStringExtra("text");
        if (havestring != null) {
            Global.list1.add(havestring);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        Button backbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backbtn);
        backbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

row.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So how to set custom adapter that will add corresponding image with string added.
Can it be done using if else statement in custom adapter???
Please do help me
for same.
Can anyone help me out???

Comment: Where' the List_row xml?

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     android:orientation="horizontal"     android:layout_width="match_parent"     android:layout_height="match_parent"> <ImageView     android:id="@+id/imageview"     android:layout_width="60dp"     android:layout_height="60dp"     android:padding="5dp"    />                      <TextView             android:id="@+id/textview2"             android:layout_width="wrap_content"             android:layout_height="wrap_content"             android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>     </LinearLayout>

Comment: This is my row xml

Comment: Can someone help me out with this???

Comment: Are you retriving the image from drawables folder? Have you tried passing the ID of the Image via Intent?

Comment: Yes.I want to try it by passing integer ID.But I can't make out how to do custom adapter for same. Can you just help me out with custom adapter please...???

Comment: You could just modify the `Constructor` of your Custom `Adapter` to be able to pass an image id.. Then set the `ImageView` resource to that id.. I'm assuming this is just ***one image for all*** the `ListView` items..

Comment: It would help if you can post your CustomAdapter.